# Apache mod_rewrite friendly url subdirectory?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have seen some answers on how to achieve this but what if the current(.htacces) directory is a subdirectory of root dir. So let's say the .htaccess file is located here: `/public_html/projects/project2/.htaccess` The content of .htaccess :

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^calendar/(.*) calendar?news_id=$1 [QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Now when I try to access my `/public_html/projects/project2/calendar.php`
whith a parameter it does not work.

```
http://myserver.com/projects/project2/calendar/new-event-for-test
```

and PHP says undefinded index news_id.

```
//...
trigger_error($_GET['news_id']);
//...
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please, try 
RewriteRule ^calendar/(.*) calendar?news_id=$1 [QSA, L]

because you redirect twice

Comment: I don't believe, calendar.php even is called. I rather suspect, you get a 404 not found.

Comment: RewriteRule ^calendar/(.*) calendar?news_id=$1 [QSA, L] did not help. I get only plain text from this page. In `Dev Console is a lot of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` < . PHP Logs says: `Undefined index: news_id` . I think that apache treats this as directory. Maybe the rule that remove .php from url is causing this?

Comment: I tried these rules in my test environment, and the behaviour is different. Maybe you have additional rules in this or another .htaccess.